# Docker for Windows can't reach the database in Windows 10 enterprise evaluation

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I was trying **Docker Desktop for Windows** on a VM with **Windows 10 Enterprise evaluation**.
This is the error that I get:

[image]

I've searched round here but I haven't found nothing usefull. I have opened the log file and found error message like:

> Failed to setup server socket listening on hyperv-connect://... Failed
> to contact the database on \.\pipe\dockerDataBase.... File not found
> Unable to write to database (continue like image above)

Nobody have idea? I've accepted the initial prompt when Docker asks me if I want to enable the Hyper-V feature and restart the computer after activation. Could it be a problem of nested virtualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the nested virtualization. Docker for Windows use Hyper-V behind the scene, Hyper-V was on the host machine too, so there's two nested virtual machine.

The steps are:

1. Create virtual machine named Docker (the one where Docker will be installed on) without dynamic memory allocation
2. Open Powershell and `Set-VMProcessor -VMName "Docker" -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`
3. Install SO and Docker for Windows as usual

**Be aware host machine and guest machine must share the same build number and both needs to be a Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it after I executed this command on a Powershell window:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto
```

I also had to enable CPU virtualization on the hardware properties of the virtual machine *(I'm using VMWare vCenter, that might not be needed in your case)*